# Executing a function every 5 hours, using Alarm API in Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, firefox-os

I'd like to write a simple application for FirefoxOS that send an email to some address every, say, 5 hours. How can I do that? Some folks pointed me to use the Alarm API but I can't figure out how to use them to accomplish that task.

Answer (score 4):

[Alarm API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Alarm)

> The Alarm API provides access to the device alarm settings, which can
>   schedule a notification or for an application to be started at a
>   specific time. For example, some applications like alarm-clock,
>   calendar or auto-update might need to utilize the Alarm API to trigger
>   particular device behaviors at specified time points.

First you need to [add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MozAlarmsManager.add) an alarm. Then, set your application as [alarm handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MozAlarmsManager.add):

> First, the applications must include alarm to the messages property of
>   its application manifest with the URL to the document which registers
>   the callback function to be used when an alarm is dispatched.

```
"messages": [
  { "alarm": "/index.html" }
]
```

> Second, the application must bind a callback function with the alarm
>   message

```
navigator.mozSetMessageHandler("alarm", function (mozAlarm) { 
  alert("alarm fired: " + JSON.stringify(mozAlarm.data)); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i think here you have what you need. just follow the examples given there https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Alarm